# Speakers don't play sound, headphones do.

Tags: sound

I'm using elementary OS loki in a HP laptop.

I don't know why, but sometimes I cannot hear any sound coming from the speakers, but it does work when plugging headphones. In Pulse Audio the speakers appear as "unavailable".

[image: speakers unavailable]

Comment: Is it 'sometimes' every time when you restart dual boot windows 10 and start eos after the restart? This is what I have discovered with my Hp laptop

Comment: I found out the problem shows up when I mute the speaker in windows and then boot up to elementary. It's a very strange behaviour.

Comment: Can you try to reboot from windows into eos, without muted sound, and check out does the problem occures or not?

Comment: Yes. If I turn off from windows with the sound on, it stays on in eos. For context, I also get much better sound on windows than on eos and the mute button in my laptop has a LED that turns on when muted in windows but not in eos.